# What exactly is the difference between a functional relational schema and a functional dependencies diagram

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, functional-dependencies

After some googling, it appears they are really the same thing? However for one of my assignments I need to include both so I'm really not sure how to differ the two diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

[In Bunge's ontology, models of things are called "functional schemata".](https://books.google.ca/books?id=m22sBwAAQBAJ) (Ie "functional schemas".) Ie abstract characterizations of a thing or state of affairs, whether physical or conceptual. They allow us to reason about that thing/state.

So a *functional relational schema* is a functional schema where the schema is relational. This is called a *logical schema* or *database schema* in relational information modeling. (From a relational point of view, these are the same thing.) Ie *relations/tables* with their *attributes/columns* and their *meanings/predicates*. (Sometimes "schema" is used to include *constraints* and/or other information. But you don't need any other information to update and query.) A predicate is a fill-in-the-named-blanks statement. We can replace the names by the corresponding values from a row with those column names. We get a *statement/proposition*. The rows that make a true statement go into the table. That is how we know how to update a base table and what each row in or not in a query result tells us.

We can describe tables and their columns using a relational DBMS Data Definition Language (DDL) or Entity-Relationship Diagram (ERD):

**SUPPLIER**(Supp#,Supplier) -- supplier *Supp#* is named *Supplier*
**ORDER**(Order#,OrdNo) -- order *Order#* was placed on *OrdDate*
**ORDERLINE**(Order#,Prod#,Quantity) -- order *Order#* orders *Quantity* of product *Prod#*
**PRODUCT**(Prod#,Product,Price) -- product *Prod#* is named *Product* and costs $*Price*
**receives**(Supp#,Order#) -- supplier *Supp#* receives order *Order#*
**contains**(Order#,Prod#) -- order *Order#* contains orderline (*Order#*,*Prod#*)

[image]

A *functional dependency (FD) diagram* or list shows what sets of attributes of a table functionally determine others. It explicitly gives the FDs in some cover for all the FDs in the table. A cover for some FDs is a set of FDs that imply them all. (Normally, a minimal/irreducible cover. A minimal/irreducible cover is one that doesn't contain a smaller one.)

**ORDERLINE**
Product → Quantity
Order#, Product → Quantity

[image]

Given a relational table schema and its FD diagram or list, the table can be normalized. Given a (functional) relational database schema and a FD diagram or list for each of its tables, the tables can be normalized to give a schema where all the tables are in some minimal normal form.